# How to limit user input?

Tags: c++

I want my program to print Error when the user inputs a number(n) 151 or above.

Here is my source code. Sorry I am a beginner.

[image]

Comment: Please post code as text.  You might want to read [ask] with a [mcve]

Comment: Why is `n` being read inside a loop... iterating with `n`... 

Comment: sorry im a beginner

Comment: *Don't* post your code behind external links. Post it directly *in* the question, as *text*.

Comment: I tried posting your image into my IDE, but it didn't work.  No posted code as text == no help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a check after `cin >> n;` as follows

```
if(n > 151) {
  cout << "Too big!";
  exit(0);
}
```

Comment: @ElcidMiranda glad that I was able to help, you can press the tick button next to my answer if you think it solved your problem

Comment: where is this tick button?

Comment: @ElcidMiranda see https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235